# Socket bindings in JBoss EAP 6.1

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, application-server

What is the difference between `outbound-socket-binding` and `socket-binding`? When should I use one over another? I guess there are differences but I am not able to find any documentation on it. Tried to read the XSD, but didn't find any interesting.

```
    <socket-binding name="smtp-noreply" port="465" fixed-port="false"/>
    <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
        <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
    </outbound-socket-binding>
```